# Dynamically style a React element

Tags: reactjs, styling

I am trying to dynamically style a React element: In the nav bar, I would like to make the font color of the `<div>` displaying the current page to be different from the other `<div>`s representing other pages. I have passed into my `<NavBar>` component's props the params representing the current page.

From this information, I have figured out a way to achieve what I am trying to do: I store the `<div>`s representing the page links in an object and wrap the selected page in another `<div>` carrying a 'selected'class name.

However, I could envision scenarios where this solution would disrupt styling in place since it adds a wrapper element and classes within the wrapper element would take precedence over the 'selected' class.

Does anyone know a better way? I have posted my solution and the context below:

```
export default class NavBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const pages = {
      my_subscribed_docs:
        <div className='nav__row2-item'>Documents I'm Subscribed To</div>,
      my_created_docs:
        <div className='nav__row2-item'>Documents I've Created</div>,
      new_doc:
        <div className='nav__row2-item'>
          <div className="plus-icon">+</div>
          <div className='nav__row2-text_left-of-icon'>New Document</div>
        </div>,
    };

    const currentPage = this.props.path.slice(1);
    pages[currentPage] =
      <div className='nav__row2-item--selected'>{pages[currentPage]}</div>;
    debugger;

    return (
        <nav>
          <div className="nav__row1">
            <div className="nav__logo">Worksheet Generator</div>
            <div style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} onClick={this.props.logout}>
              Logout
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="nav__row2" >
            { Object.values(pages).map( page => (
              <div key={shortid.generate()}>{page}</div>)
            ) }
          </div>
        </nav>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: By the way, I tried doing `pages[currentPage].props.className += ' nav__row2-item--selected'` and I got an error saying that it cannot be modified. Same thing for the element's style object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically add a `class` to your component, I recommend using [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) library. This is pretty much the way to do it when using external stylesheets.